# How do I stream a file into a matrix in C++ boost ublas?

Tags: c++, boost, matrix, ifstream, ublas

I'm trying to read in a file that contains matrix data into a boost matrix. "" is already supposed to have operator overloads for this sort of thing and I can get it to write to a standard stream (cout).  I don't know what's wrong with going the other way.  I'm fairly new to C++, so I'm guessing I'm making an incorrect assumption regarding file streams, but it seemed like it made sense.  Here are the web pages I'm going on:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/ifstream/

Here's my code:

```
using namespace std;
matrix<double> M;
ifstream s("C:\temp\perm.txt", ifstream::in);

s >> M;
s.close();

std::cout << M;
```

Here's what my file looks like:

```
[4,4]((0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1),(0,1,0,0),(1,0,0,0))
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with what you have shown. [Here is a small example I made](http://ideone.com/0Kb8L), what is the problem?

Comment: @Jesse But...something is strange on ideone. When I fork your program, I get the following error `prog.cpp:1:38: fatal error: boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>` - here's the program - http://ideone.com/06Zsrf. What gives?

Comment: @lifebalance: ideone removed boost support. Use [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdb16549d800db84) instead as it supports boost.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks! - How do you specify the stdin on coliru?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example, please try it out and see what happens. If this doesn't work, I suspect that the problem is that the file path is wrong or the program is failing to read from the text file:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> m;
    std::ifstream s("C:\temp\perm.txt");
    if (!s)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (!s >> m)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to write to matrix" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Printing matrix: ";
    std::cout << m;
}
```